# visual studio nested bookmark folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there any Visual Studio 2017 extension or plugin what enables nested bookmark folders?

eg.

```
  FolderA
    -bookmark1
    -FolderB
      -bookmark2
      -bookmark3
```

Comment: I want this too. Just understood that this functionality is missing